# Where to go for groups after Fraleigh

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I have been studying Fraleigh's *Abstract algebra* in order to learn groups. Up to know I am at sec 16, Group Action on a set and I'm starting to feel that I am losing the development of the arguments. I also found a little bit hard to grasp Factor groups, but now I think I have an idea how to manipulate them.

I intend to follow the quest of learning groups, and my question is for a reference(s). I have self-study it so far so a pedagogical source would be much appreciated.

I really want to tackle Sylow theory, but the group actions as it is in Fraleigh seemed scant to me.

Comment: After, actually. I did not like too much the Action on groups that he exposes. I understand that this is also fundamental to tackle Sylow theory, is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

*Abstract Algebra* by David Steven Dummit and Richard M. Foote is a popular one.

Answer (score 3):

Algebra by Michael Artin is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

I am also reading Fraleigh now. It is good for you to use Fraleigh to obtain rings and fields.  I followed the advice of the following link:

https://bfhaha.blogspot.com/p/abstract-algebra-first-course.html

It is a Taiwan chinese version, I hope it can be translate by google in your browser.

It says that Nicholson's is good for group theory, and Fraleigh's is as mentioned above. Dummit's for module...blablalba...

Comment: In a word, ideas that comes from his advice are:
(1) Theory:
Groups: Nicholson; 
Rings and Fields: Fraleigh;
Galois Theory: Hungerford's Introduction;
Module: Dummit & Foote;
(2) Applications:
Wallpaers: Gallian;
Rubik's: Joyner;
Coloring: Nicholson;
Music: Budden.